# Insert comment form on Post detail page. django- blog app

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-forms

I have trying this from 2-3 days. I want to insert my comment form on post detail page.
My form is not showing on that page.
I have followed this tutorial for the comment model.
I have another app for account which is used for signup purpose.
model.py

```
        class Post(models.Model):
        author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        text = models.TextField()
        created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
        published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
        def __str__(self):
                return self.title
        def publish(self):
                self.published_date = timezone.now()
                self.save()
        def approved_comments(self):
            return self.comments.filter(approved_comment=True)       

class Comment(models.Model):
        post = models.ForeignKey('Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
        author = models.CharField(verbose_name ='Username',max_length=200)
        text = models.TextField(verbose_name ='Comment')
        email = models.EmailField(default='')
        created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
        approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

        def approve(self):
            self.approved_comment = True
            self.save()

        def __str__(self):
            return self.text
```

view.py

```
def post_detail(request, pk):

    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})  


def add_comment_to_post(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/add_comment_to_post.html', {'form': form})

@login_required
def comment_approve(request, pk):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=pk)
    comment.approve()
    return redirect('post_detail', pk=comment.post.pk)

@login_required
def comment_remove(request, pk):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=pk)
    comment.delete()
    return redirect('post_detail', pk=comment.post.pk)
```

urls.py

```
path('post/<int:pk>/comment/', views.add_comment_to_post, name='add_comment_to_post'),
    path('comment/<int:pk>/approve/', views.comment_approve, name='comment_approve'),
    path('comment/<int:pk>/remove/', views.comment_remove, name='comment_remove'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
```

Please help me out to find a way to insert it in my post_deatil.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want the same page to see the post and also add a comment you only need one view like:

```
def post_details(request, pk):
post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
if request.method == "POST":
    form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        comment = form.save(commit=False)
        comment.post = post
        comment.save()
        return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
else:
    form = CommentForm()
return render(request, 'blog/post_details.html', {'form': form, 'post': post})
```

Then your url will be like:

```
path('post/<int:pk>/', views.post_details, name='post-details'),
```

And finally you have to mix both of your templates, first showing the information of the post and on the bottom adding the form.

With that you will be able to delete the `add_comment_to_post` view and url.

Comment: Reverse for 'post_detail' not found. 'post_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.